# Boost builder don't see ctype.h file

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying build Boost library v.1.64.0 on Windows 7 by running

```
bootstrap.bat
```

from root Boost folder, but it failed because not found files 'ctype.h', 'stddef.h', etc.

I found this header files in folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt
```

How I can specify this folder to include path, that use boost builder (compiler)?

Comment: By building `boost` in a `Visual Studio Command Prompt` as specified in [boost getting started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/more/getting_started/windows.html). The `msvc command prompt` sets up environment variables for include folders, etc.